# how to dd capture partitions of a VMware Player VM

Tags: linux, vmware-player, dd

I have a Linux VM that runs in VMware Player. It has **/dev/sda1** mounted as **/boot** and **/dev/sda2** mounted as **/**.  I want to use **dd** to capture both partitions. I now know from the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399821/using-dd-to-capture-from-vmware-and-restore-to-ec2-xen-fails) that to capture the partition cleanly, the partitions should be unmounted at the time of capture.

The question is, how do I boot to a live cd or second OS within the same VMware Player session so that I can unmount the two partitions and then capture them cleanly with dd?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount an .ISO file of a LiveCD by using the Devices->CD/DVD menu option in VMWare Player. You can then get a command line, and then dd each of the `/dev/` devices that you want. If you create a third drive, you could mount that to have somewhere to `dd` to.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I boot to a live cd or second OS within VMware Player

Precisely in the same way as with a real desktop: Shut down the OS which you want to capture. Insert a CD (in this case a virtual CD on an iso) and boot from that.

> so that I can unmount the two partitions and then capture them 
>   cleanly with dd?

No need to unmount anything. Shut the to be capture OS down. At this time partitions should be clean and unmounted. Then boot something which leaves everything unmounted.